# Select elements in a range of dates

Tags: android, sql, cursor

I'm having serious trouble on getting a query that shows me elements of a DB that has a date that fits X day backward from today.

the code i have right now is similar

```
public Cursor getLastClienti(String days){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DataBaseHelper.TABLE_CLIENTI, DataBaseHelper.COLUMNS_TABLE_CLIENTI,
                null, null, null, null,  DataBaseHelper.COLUMNS_TABLE_CLIENTI[0]);
        return cursor;
    }
```

what i'm trying to achieve is a query that gives me the elements of the table that has the field `data_visita` between today and the param `days`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the day as integer value and minus it from today. then get date in your specific format and use it in selection query

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
Date endTime = c.getTime();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -d);  // go 'd' day back
Date startTime = c.getTime();
```